# awk sum in for loop

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have this script:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN{
    FS="=|,"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
    printf "\n"
    printf "%-7s %s", "Count", "Amount"
    printf "\n"
    OFS="\t"
}
/phrase/{
    for (i=4; i 3<= 5; i++ )
        if ($i != "") a[$i]++
}

END{
    for (i in a) {print a[i], i; tot++}
    printf "\n"
    printf " ***** %s total wins *****", tot
    printf "\n"
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
Count   Amount
1       20
1       22
1       29
1       37
1       38
1       45
1       46
2       80
1       99
1       800

 ***** 10 total unique amounts *****
```

I would like to also print out the sum of the second field, but notice the count amounts vary from 1 to many. Should there be a while loop within the for loop to sum up the count or do the math at the end of the script in the END?

Thanks for any hints you can supply!

Here's sample data which gawk is extracting with

```
gawk -F"=|," '/phrase/ {print $4}' file
80
800
20
46
38
45
99
80
29
22
37
```

Data example before parsed:

```
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=80
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=800
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=20
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=46
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=38
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=45
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=99
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=80
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=29
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=22
.\phrase(100): [LOG] API context: context=3, amount=37
```

expected result:

```
Count   Amount
1       20
1       22
1       29
1       37
1       38
1       45
1       46
2       80
1       99
1       800

***** 10 total unique amounts *****
***** 1296 sum totals         *****
```

Comment: Please post sample Input_file in CODE TAGS in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I've added some data. I hope it's useful for you.

Comment: You are asking sum for 2nd field but you have showed data for 4th field, please post full Input_file rather than posting pieces of it.

Comment: The input file has been posted. I'm asking for the count field that's created by the for loop to be used to calculate the results and print at the end.

Comment: I don't think so whole Input_file is posted, please post more lines and full Input_file in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I hope this is more clear for you now.

Comment: Im curious - what do you think `i 3<= 5` means in `for (i=4; i 3<= 5; i++ )`?

Comment: @EdMorton, I clearly don't know. `a[$NF]++;t+=$NF` is much simpler.

Comment: But you must've had SOMETHING in mind that you intended it to do when you wrote it and that's all I'm asking: when you wrote that code, what was it that you thought it would do?

Comment: It came from a previous script, so I jammed it in to fit for this case. Could you explain how the sum is working? `t+=$NF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it should be:

```
awk -F= '{a[$NF]++;t+=$NF} # You can calculate the total here
         END{
             for(i in a) print a[i], i
             printf "%s uniq\n", length(a)
             printf "%s total\n", t
         }' a.txt
```

I omitted sorting and printing the headers for brevity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know about the `length()` function - very handy. I'm making your answer the acceptable one out of readability.

Comment: `n=asorti(a,b,"@val_num_asc"); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[b[i]],b[i]` will be the sorted version.

Comment: @RegisteredUser You are welcome. Providing a simple to read answer was my intention. :)

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F'=' '{a[$NF]++;sum+=$NF} END{print "Count   Amount";for(i in a){print a[i]"\t"i;};print "***** " length(a),"total unique amounts *****" RS "***** " sum "sum totals         *****"}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Count   Amount
2       80
1       45
1       37
1       46
1       29
1       38
1       20
1       22
1       800
1       99
***** 10 total unique amounts *****
***** 1296sum totals         *****
```

Comment: This is printing the count and amount columns correctly, but the sum total is not correct. Notice there are two 80 amount records but only one is being counted.

Comment: It's also interesting that you're printing the header column information in the END section.

Comment: @RegisteredUser, no, I am getting count for 80 is 2. Please check my edited output which I am getting after running the code.

Comment: You're right, the count is correct, but the sum total is wrong.

Comment: @RegisteredUser, please check now. Actually since it is taking only 1 unique count in array so it was skipping all count's sum. Added it now.